# database update with Java dynamically

Tags: java, database

I am a beginner in java and I came to a problem. I tried many ways but couldn't succeed. I want to update my database in java but I don't know what exactly my error is. Here is my code.

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

   String username=jTextField1.getText();
   String password=jPasswordField1.getText();
   String new_pass=jPasswordField2.getText();
   update(1,username,new_pass);
}
```

and the function is called as:

```
public void update(int id, String name, String pass) {

    int i = 0;
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database", "root", "");

        String sql = "UPDATE user_pass SET id=?, password=? WHERE username=? ";
        PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setInt(1, id);
        System.out.println("Yeha samma thik xa");
        pst.setString(2, name);
        pst.setString(3, pass);
        pst.executeUpdate();
        System.out.println("Updated Successifully");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Successifully updated! ");

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry there is an error\nPlease check the information provided  ", " ", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }

}
```

Comment: What problems is this code having? Are you getting any errors? Misbehaviors? Something else?

Comment: yes it says you have an sql error near where clause

Comment: @MithunAdhikari what does it say specifically.

Comment: Should username be 3 and password be 2?

Comment: @PeterSmith Thank you so much for your concern. But I found a solution out. Use the query as

String sql=UPDATE user_pass SET id='"+id+"', password='"+password+"' WHERE username='"+username+"' ";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the query itself. It should have been

```
String sql=UPDATE user_pass SET id='"+id+"', password='"+password+"' WHERE username='"+username+"' ";
```

not this
`String sql = "UPDATE user_pass SET id=?, password=? WHERE username=? ";`

And everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know what exactly my error is.

This is because you catch the error.

```
} catch (Exception ex) {
```

but you ignore it throwing it away.  If you print the error with a stack trace you will have some idea of where and why you are getting an error.

If this doesn't help, I suggest using the debugger in your IDE.  This can help you diagnose both the error and the cause.

Answer (score 0):

```
catch (Exception ex) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry there is an error\nPlease check the information provided  ", " ", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}
```

You should print your "Exception ex". Then you can figure out what the error is and then you can fix it.

For beginners: put "System.out.println(ex)" in the catch-block.